# How to fix UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' decode byte 0xc0 read in sql file

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, pymssql, cp1251

This is tx.sql

```
 DECLARE @Cnt INT,
    @ParticipantID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

SELECT ParticipantID INTO #ids
FROM dbo.rbd_Participants
/* sun */
WHERE surname='Пупкин'
```

This is python script

```
with open('tx.sql', 'r') as f:
    script = f.read().decode('utf8') 
script = re.sub(r'\/\*.*?\*\/', '', script, flags=re.DOTALL)multiline comment
script = re.sub(r'--.*$', '', script, flags=re.MULTILINE)  line comment

sql = []
do_execute = False
for line in script.split(u'\n'):
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue
    elif line.upper() == u'GO':
        do_execute = True

    else:
        sql.append(line)
        do_execute = line.endswith(u';')
        #print line


cur.execute(u'\n'.join(sql).encode('utf8'))
```

Problem line: `script = f.read().decode('utf8')`

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position
>   134: invalid start byte

I have tried

```
script = f.read().decode('cp1251')
```

but line

```
cur.execute(u'\n'.join(sql).encode('utf8')) 
print (u'\n'.join(sql)).encode('utf8')
DECLARE @Cnt INT,
@ParticipantID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SELECT ParticipantID INTO #ids
FROM dbo.rbd_Participants
WHERE surname='РџСѓРїРєРёРЅ'
```

**How to make the correct line?**

> WHERE surname='РџСѓРїРєРёРЅ'

There must be a string

> WHERE surname='Пупкин'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the data correctly. It is your **print** statement that is incorrect:

```
print (u'\n'.join(sql)).encode('utf8')
```

Your terminal or console doesn't support UTF-8, so it is showing you the wrong data. Don't encode, leave that to Python.